# Find the maximum size of a subset of a permutation of size $n$, such that the sum of any 2 numbers in the subset isn't contained in the subset.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Let $S$ be a subset of a permutation of size $n$, such that for any $2$ numbers in $S$, their sum isn't contained in $S$. Prove that the maximum size of $S$ is $\left \lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\right \rfloor + 1$.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your use of the word $\it permutation$ here, but I will assume that you mean: $\lfloor{n \over 2}\rfloor +1$ is the maximum size of a subset $S$ of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ where if two numbers are in $S$, their sum is not in $S$.  Some hints:

1. Verify by hand that it is true for very small examples $n \leq 5$.
2. To get max $\geq \lfloor {n \over 2} \rfloor +1$, construct an $S$ of that size. Continue with small examples such as $6 \leq n \leq 10$ if arbitrary $n$ is giving you problems.
3. To get $\leq$ try using induction. More specifically, given an $S$ for $n = k+2$, try to construct one for $n=k$ of size at least $|S| -1$. You will find it splits into two cases.